# Improve slide effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have created a simple slider

html

```
<div id="sldvid1" class="slider" >
    <img picnum="1" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/qa.SentientPrime.media/Ecommerce/44c068f106659d396f1ea0f2401f3879/1/thumbnail1.png" />
      <img picnum="2"  style="display:none;" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/qa.SentientPrime.media/Ecommerce/44c068f106659d396f1ea0f2401f3879/1/thumbnail7.png" />
      <img picnum="3" style="display:none;" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/qa.SentientPrime.media/Ecommerce/44c068f106659d396f1ea0f2401f3879/1/thumbnail14.png" />
</div>
<hr>
<div id="sldvid2" class="slider" >
    <img picnum="1" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/qa.SentientPrime.media/Ecommerce/44c068f106659d396f1ea0f2401f3879/1/thumbnail1.png" />
      <img picnum="2"  style="display:none;" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/qa.SentientPrime.media/Ecommerce/44c068f106659d396f1ea0f2401f3879/1/thumbnail7.png" />
      <img picnum="3" style="display:none;" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/qa.SentientPrime.media/Ecommerce/44c068f106659d396f1ea0f2401f3879/1/thumbnail14.png" />
</div>
```

$

```
var timer1 = setInterval(runSlide, 1000);
var curnum = 1;
function runSlide()
{
    curnum = $(".slider img:visible").attr('picnum');
    //$("#sldvid1 img[picnum=" + curnum + "]").fadeOut(); 
    if(curnum == 3){
        curnum = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        curnum++;
    }
   // $(".slider img").hide();
   //$(".slider img[picnum=" + curnum + "]").show(); 
     $(".slider img").hide();
   $(".slider img[picnum=" + curnum + "]").show(); 
    //console.log(curnum);

}
```

CSS

```
.slider{
    height:50px;
}
```

Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/mparvez1986/vf401e2y/

Everything is working fine, I just need some one to improve effect so that it could effect like moving from left to right, I tried with some effect, but it seems it required some css manipulation as well

Thanks

Comment: if you are stuck somewhere , let us know otherwise make a project on github.

Comment: Yes, i want to put an effect to moving from left to right slowly

Comment: hey, why don't you use a allready developped slider, like slick.js ?

Comment: I want to do something by myself.

Comment: I think it needs some css manipulation

Comment: Well, more that this. You need to clone the items aswell for the infinit effect, make all items side by side inside a wrapper with a fixed width and an overflow hidden. You need to get in js the width of the item, and slide the items with transform: translate(xx, yy) for exemple.

Comment: What effect you want exaclty and when ? and use data attr for this `data-picnum="3"`

Comment: And take a look on http://api.jquery.com/animate/, if you describe exactly what effect you i want i can make it

Comment: Please have a look on jsfiddle, i want images to move left to right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I modified your code to create a carousel where images are slid in and out. I accomplished this by animating the `margin-left` CSS property with jQuery. I specified a size for the `.slider` class and used `overflow: hidden;` to ensure the sliding images were not displayed outside of it.

If you wish, you can change the transition effect by changing the CSS property that is animated and ensuring that the elements are in the correct position for the animation before it begins.

You can also change the speed of the animation by changing the [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Unnamed_numerical_constants) `1000` that I've left in the calls to `animate`. This number is specified in milliseconds.

By the way, I should point out that while custom HTML attributes are allowed in HTML5 they should begin with `data-`; they are called [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes).

## [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ninjakannon/uzp0qt4d/2/)

### HTML

```
<div id="sldvid1" class="slider">
    <img class="active" data-slide-to="0" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/qa.SentientPrime.media/Ecommerce/44c068f106659d396f1ea0f2401f3879/1/thumbnail1.png"/>
    <img data-slide-to="1" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/qa.SentientPrime.media/Ecommerce/44c068f106659d396f1ea0f2401f3879/1/thumbnail7.png"/>
    <img data-slide-to="2" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/qa.SentientPrime.media/Ecommerce/44c068f106659d396f1ea0f2401f3879/1/thumbnail14.png"/>
</div>
<hr>
<div id="sldvid2" class="slider">
    <img class="active" data-slide-to="0" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/qa.SentientPrime.media/Ecommerce/44c068f106659d396f1ea0f2401f3879/1/thumbnail1.png"/>
    <img data-slide-to="1" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/qa.SentientPrime.media/Ecommerce/44c068f106659d396f1ea0f2401f3879/1/thumbnail7.png"/>
    <img data-slide-to="2" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/qa.SentientPrime.media/Ecommerce/44c068f106659d396f1ea0f2401f3879/1/thumbnail14.png"/>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.slider {
    position: relative;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slider img {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

.slider .active {
    display: inline-block;
}

.slider .sliding {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

### JavaScript

```
var timer = setInterval(runSlide, 2000);

function runSlide() {
    // Slide each slider on the page.
    $(".slider").each(function (index, element) {
        // Get the elements involved in the slide.
        var numChildren = $(this).children().length;
        var activeChild = $(this).children(".active");
        var activeSlideTo = $(activeChild).attr("data-slide-to");
        var nextSlideTo = (parseInt(activeSlideTo) + 1) % numChildren;
        var nextChild = $(this).find("*[data-slide-to=" + nextSlideTo + "]");

        // Prepare for slide.
        $(activeChild).css("margin-left", "0%");
        $(nextChild).css("margin-left", "-100%");
        $(activeChild).addClass("sliding");
        $(nextChild).addClass("sliding");
        $(activeChild).removeClass("active");

        // Slide using CSS margin-left.
        $(activeChild).animate({"margin-left": "100%"}, 1000, function () {
            $(this).removeClass("sliding");
        });
        $(nextChild).animate({"margin-left": "0%"}, 1000, function () {
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $(this).removeClass("sliding");
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting that! Done.

Comment: Okay, [check out this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ninjakannon/uzp0qt4d/3/).

Comment: Thousand tons of Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Ended with following

```
setInterval(function() { 
  $('#sldvid1 > img:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#sldvid1');
},  3000);
```